# How to progmmatically open a web browser once the server successfully starts

Tags: ruby, thin

I am using ruby thin to run a server on my local computer. In my ruby code, as soon as the server starts successfully, I want to programmatically open a web browser to send request to that server. How can I do that?

I have a code like this:

```
    Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new do
        map("/resource/"){run(Rack::File.new("/"))}
        map("/") do
            run(->env{
                h = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env["QUERY_STRING"])
                [200, {},[some_method_to_dynamically_generate_content(h)]]})
        end
    end, Port: 3000)
```

which observes request from `localhost:3000` or file requests on that directory, and I want to put a command within this ruby code to run `google-chrome localhost:3000`, but I do not know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on linux, you can use

1. a curl command to achieve the same `curl http://localhost:3000`, read more [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)
2. `Kernel#system` method, `system("google-chrome http://localhost:3000")`

Comment: With `curl`, do I need to keep polling, or is there are way that I can be notified from thin once it starts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on MacOS X,

```
open URL
```

will open the default web browser with the URL.